# Inner join using where in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I prepare the following query in laravel?

```
SELECT u.*
FROM `users` AS u 
INNER JOIN `roles_users` AS r 
ON u.id = r.user_id 
WHERE r.role_id = ".Role::USER_CLIENT_COACH."
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries) like so:

```
DB::table('users')
        ->join('roles_users', 'users.id', '=', 'roles_users.user_id')
        ->select('users.id')
        ->where('roles_users.role_id' = Role::USER_CLIENT_COACH)
        ->get();
```

Wrote this very quickly so check the syntax, but generally this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! I did this and it worked:  $user_list = User::where('users.user_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->join('users_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'users_roles.user_id')
            ->where('users_roles.role_id', '=', Role::USER_CLIENT_COACH)
            ->get();